# logic app throwing extended ajax error while running with payload in adf logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

this is the schema in https result body

```
{
"properties": {
"DataFactoryName": {
"type": "string"
        },
"EmailTo": {
"type": "string"
        },
"Message": {
"type": "string"
        },
"PipelineName": {
"type": "string"
        },
"Result": {
"type": "string"
        },
"Subject": {
"type": "string"
        }
    },
"type": "object"
}
```

==================
payload is this:

{ "DataFactoryName": "test",
"EmailTo": "aniruddhya.dutta@netsle.com",
"Message":"Failed",
"PipelineName": "test",
"Result": "Failed",
"Subject": "test" }

But logic app is giving error stating cannot initiate.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same schema and the payload but there were no errors for me. I recommend you to check the logic app and follow the way how I did.

[image]

[image]

[image]